# Proper way to marshal char* to string using C# interoperability. Get "a heap has been corrupted" exception

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling, wrapper

not a lot of experience in C++.  Attempting to Marshal `char*` in C to `string` in C#, using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`, but I get a `"a heap has been corrupted" exception`.  It does however work in reverse (`string` in C# to `char*` in C).  What am I doing wrong here?

More details:
on C side, this is the struct:

```
struct STRUCTV
{
    char* _pretext;
    char* _result;
};
```

this is C function signature: `void add_all_numbers(STRUCTV *structV);`

This is C# side

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCTV
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _pretext; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _result;  //<----THIS ISNT WORKING

}

internal partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport(
    "Library.dll",
    EntryPoint = "function1",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void function1(ref STRUCTV structV);
}
```

this is how i use it:

```
STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = null;
NativeMethods.function1(ref myStruct); //<---- ntdll.dll : A heap has been corrupted"
Console.WriteLine(myStruct._result);
```

In case this is important, this is what happens inside C code if that's important:

```
string resultstring = GetResult();
char* result = new char[resultstring.length() + 1];
strcpy_s(result, resultstring.length() + 1, resultstring.c_str());
structV->_result = result;
```

Some additional information.  it works if I don't marshal the char* as string in _result, and i want to understand why.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCTV
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _pretext; 
    public IntPtr _result;
}

STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = IntPtr.Zero;
NativeMethods.function1(ref myStruct);
string resultString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(myStruct._result);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: Write a C++/clr wrapper, it gives you more control over lifecycles (when you need to copy, pin etc)

Comment: @PepijnKramer C++/CLI is windows specific.

Comment: Well you didn't specify portability ;) And I see .dll in your question, not .so

Comment: @PepijnKramer.  fair assumption given dll reference ;-).  to clarify, i am trying to understand data marshalling in general.  i didn't think .so vs .dll is relevant.  is it?

Comment: No not really, but marshalling isn't your only problem. So is the total difference in lifecycle managment of objects in C# and C++.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, not sure what you're referring to.   Are you referring to me not cleaning up all the manually allocated memory with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`?   I left that part out of this example.  is it relevant?

Answer (score 0):

The C# code is assuming that it's responsible for passing the `_result` string into the C++ code as a preallocated `char*` pointer.  But, the C++ code is actually allocating its own memory for the `_result` string and returning the pointer back to the C# code.  So, you shouldn't marshal the `_result` string using `LPStr` the way you are trying to do, since it's output data not input data.

Using `IntPtr` is one viable way to handle this. You can then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` to convert the `IntPtr` into a C# `string`. However, in this case, do note that the C++ code is `new[]`'ing the `_result` string, and C# cannot free that memory.  So, you will have to export another function from the C++ code which the C# code can then call to pass the returned `IntPtr` back to C++ so it can properly `delete[]` the memory, eg:

```cpp
struct STRUCTV
{
    char* _pretext;
    char* _result;
};

void add_all_numbers(STRUCTV *structV)
{
    ...
    string resultstring = GetResult();
    char* result = new char[resultstring.length() + 1];
    strcpy_s(result, resultstring.length() + 1, resultstring.c_str());
    structV->_result = result;
    ...
}

void free_result(char *ptr)
{
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCTV
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _pretext; 
    public IntPtr _result;
}

internal partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport(
    "Library.dll",
    EntryPoint = "add_all_numbers",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void add_all_numbers(ref STRUCTV structV);

    [DllImport(
    "Library.dll",
    EntryPoint = "free_result",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void free_result(IntPtr result);
}

STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = IntPtr.Zero;
NativeMethods.add_all_numbers(ref myStruct);
string resultString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(myStruct._result);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);    
NativeMethods.free_result(myStruct._result);
```

The alternative is to allocate the memory on the C# side instead, and then have the C++ code just fill the memory, eg:

```cpp
struct STRUCTV
{
    char* _pretext;
    char* _result;
    int _result_max_size;
};

void add_all_numbers(STRUCTV *structV)
{
    ...
    string resultstring = GetResult();
    strcpy_s(structV->_result, structV->_result_max_size, resultstring.c_str());
    ...
}
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCTV
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _pretext; 
    public char[] _result;
    int _result_max_size;
}

internal partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport(
    "Library.dll",
    EntryPoint = "add_all_numbers",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void add_all_numbers(ref STRUCTV structV);
}

char[] buffer = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(256);
STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = buffer;
myStruct._result_max_size = buffer.Length;
NativeMethods.add_all_numbers(ref myStruct);
string resultString = new string(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);    
ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Return(buffer);

// or

IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256);
STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = buffer;
myStruct._result_max_size = 256;
NativeMethods.add_all_numbers(ref myStruct);
string resultString = Marshal.PtrToStringAni(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);    
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

Alternatively:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCTV
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string _pretext; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string _result;
    int _result_max_size;
}

internal partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport(
    "Library.dll",
    EntryPoint = "add_all_numbers",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void add_all_numbers(ref STRUCTV structV);
}

STRUCTV myStruct = new STRUCTV();
myStruct._pretext = "Pretext";
myStruct._result = "";
myStruct._result_max_size = 256;
NativeMethods.add_all_numbers(ref myStruct);
Console.WriteLine(myStruct._result);
```

Read [Default Marshalling for Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings) on MSDN for more details.